# Python - Error while copying jpg files

Tags: python, encoding, copy, jpeg

I was done with copying txt files and tried to do the same with jpg files. But I am constantly getting an encoding error.
My code is:

```
def fcopy(source, target):
data = ''
with open(source, encoding='Latin-1') as f:
    data = f.read()
    with open(target, 'w') as t:
            t.write(data)
fcopy("source.jpeg","dest.jpeg")
```

I tried using encoding = utf8 and utf16 also. But didn't work and error is as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark-II/Desktop/fileCopy.py", line 7, in <module>
    fcopy("source.jpeg","dest.jpeg")
  File "C:/Users/Mark-II/Desktop/fileCopy.py", line 3, in fcopy
    with open(source, encoding='Latin-1') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source.jpeg'
>>>
```

Please help.

Comment: Is your source file called `source.jpeg` and placed in the same working directory as your program?

Comment: Yes @Jerrybibo . The python source and the image file are in the same path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try opening the file in 'binary mode'.  This defaults to text mode per the documentation on the open method.  That explains why it works on text files and fails on non-text files like jpg images.  When opening files in binary mode you do not need to use the named parameter for the encoding.

```
def fcopy(source, target):
    with open(source, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    with open(target, 'wb') as t:
        t.write(data)

fcopy("source.jpeg","dest.jpeg")
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `None` to `data` at the top of the file?

Comment: Sorry, I mean at the top of the function.

Comment: You are correct Seth. It is not needed.  I corrected my answer. Thank you!

Comment: It worked! But I didn't understood why opening the file in binary mode makes it work? I mean if it defaults to text mode then how can it copy non text characters?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working. Your issue is with the file path. Please check the image path you gave.

Comment: No actually the source file of python and the image file are both in the same directory. So, there must not be any path problem.